# How to configure wildfly 9.0.2 to use EclipseLink under netbeans 8.1

Tags: maven, netbeans, eclipselink, wildfly-9

i have installed wildfly 9.0.2 under netbeans 8.1  and because i have already a project configured to use EclipseLink, i have tried to configure wildfly to use it.
Until now I developed my application under Glassfish Server 4. i wabt to start using WildFly. 
Project is created using maven,
Here is server log:

> 09:54:13,557 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for AdisMngmtPU
>   09:54:13,684 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."EAmvnWildfly-ear-1.0.ear".FIRST_MODULE_USE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."EAmvnWildfly-ear-1.0.ear".FIRST_MODULE_USE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment "EAmvnWildfly-ear-1.0.ear"
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:163)
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: WFLYJPA0057: PersistenceProvider 'org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider' not found
>       at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.lookupProvider(PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.java:1007)
>       at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.nextPhaseDependsOnPersistenceUnit(PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.java:1046)
>       at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.deploy(PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.java:136)
>       at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.deploy(PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.java:52)
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:156)
>       ... 5 more
>   09:54:13,703 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"EAmvnWildfly-ear-1.0.ear\".FIRST_MODULE_USE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"EAmvnWildfly-ear-1.0.ear\".FIRST_MODULE_USE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment \"EAmvnWildfly-ear-1.0.ear\"
>       Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: WFLYJPA0057: PersistenceProvider 'org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider' not found"}}
>   09:54:16,582 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "EAmvnWildfly-ear-1.0.ear" with deployment "EAmvnWildfly-ear-1.0.ear"
>   09:54:16,583 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
>   WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."EAmvnWildfly-ear-1.0.ear".FIRST_MODULE_USE
>         service jboss.deployment.unit."EAmvnWildfly-ear-1.0.ear".FIRST_MODULE_USE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."EAmvnWildfly-ear-1.0.ear".FIRST_MODULE_USE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment "EAmvnWildfly-ear-1.0.ear"
>
> 09:54:26,739 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0208: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: EAmvnWildfly-web-1.0.war) in 91ms
>   09:54:26,749 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment EAmvnWildfly-ear-1.0.ear (runtime-name: EAmvnWildfly-ear-1.0.ear) in 112ms
>   09:54:26,759 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "EAmvnWildfly-ear-1.0.ear" (runtime-name: "EAmvnWildfly-ear-1.0.ear")
>   09:54:26,789 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0207: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "EAmvnWildfly-web-1.0.war")
>   09:54:27,197 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for AdisMngmtPU
>   09:54:27,236 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."EAmvnWildfly-ear-1.0.ear".FIRST_MODULE_USE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."EAmvnWildfly-ear-1.0.ear".FIRST_MODULE_USE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment "EAmvnWildfly-ear-1.0.ear"
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:163)
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: WFLYJPA0057: PersistenceProvider 'org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider' not found
>       at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.lookupProvider(PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.java:1007)
>       at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.nextPhaseDependsOnPersistenceUnit(PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.java:1046)
>       at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.deploy(PersistenceUnitServiceHandler.java:136)
>       at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.deploy(PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.java:52)
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:156)
>       ... 5 more
>
> 09:54:27,279 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"EAmvnWildfly-ear-1.0.ear\".FIRST_MODULE_USE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"EAmvnWildfly-ear-1.0.ear\".FIRST_MODULE_USE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment \"EAmvnWildfly-ear-1.0.ear\"
>       Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: WFLYJPA0057: PersistenceProvider 'org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider' not found"}}
>   09:54:28,882 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "EAmvnWildfly-ear-1.0.ear" with deployment "EAmvnWildfly-ear-1.0.ear"
>   09:54:28,882 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
>   WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."EAmvnWildfly-ear-1.0.ear".FIRST_MODULE_USE
>         service jboss.deployment.unit."EAmvnWildfly-ear-1.0.ear".FIRST_MODULE_USE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."EAmvnWildfly-ear-1.0.ear".FIRST_MODULE_USE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment "EAmvnWildfly-ear-1.0.ear"

my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="AdisMngmtPU" transaction-type="JTA">
     <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/AdisMngmtDS</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though I'm using Wildfly 10 the steps to use EclipseLink in Wildfly 9 are identical as far as I remember (so you might tweak some file names if they include a version number):

1. Copy eclipselink-2.6.1.jar into the folder 
   `/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/eclipse/persistence/main`
2. Edit in the same folder the module.xml-file:

> ```
> <resources>
>         <resource-root path="jipijapa-eclipselink-10.0.0.Final.jar"/>
>         <resource-root path="eclipselink-2.6.1.jar">
>         <filter>
>                 <exclude path="javax/**" />
>         </filter>
> </resource-root>
>     </resources>
> ```

3. If you are using MySql you need to place the MySql-connector into 
   `/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/sql/mysql/main`
4. In your standalone-full.xml (or standalone.xml if you are using it) you need to include your DataSources and driver:

   ```
   <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:4.0">
       <datasources>
           <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
       <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
               <driver>h2</driver>
               <security>
                   <user-name>sa</user-name>
                   <password>sa</password>
               </security>
           </datasource>
           <datasource jndi-name="java:/AdisMngmtDS" pool-name="AdisMngmtDS" enabled="true">
               <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost/AdisMngmtDS</connection-url>
               <driver>mysql</driver>
               <security>
                   <user-name>root</user-name>
                   <password>password</password>
               </security>
               <validation>
                   <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                   <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
               </validation>
           </datasource>               
           <drivers>
               <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                  <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
               </driver>
               <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                   <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                   <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
               </driver>
           </drivers>
       </datasources>
   </subsystem>
   ```

(you should not delete the example datasource, because Wildfly needs this somehow)

5. You might want to include in your standalone-full.xml

   ```
   <system-properties>
       <property name="eclipselink.archive.factory" value="org.jipijapa.eclipselink.JBossArchiveFactoryImpl"/> 
   </system-properties>
   ```

If you don't include this, EclipseLink will use CamelCase for table-names, etc.

6. Your project shouldn't include any dependencies to Dom4J because you might run into ClassCast-Exceptions.

I think that was it.

Comment: Thanks i will try this and see 
but now i'm facing a new problem 
WildFly Application Server Start Failed. HTTP Connector port 8080 is already in use.

Comment: This might happen when your wildfly was not shutdown correctly and is still blocking the port (or another process uses this port). If it is your wildfly, kill the process via the process manager (or just restart your computer if you cannot find the process)

Answer (score 1):

I just had all of these problems getting eclipselink 2.6.3 to work on Wildfly 10, which is running on a windows 7, 64 bit platform.

Everything Joachim Rohde said is correct, which is also described in the Wildfly developer's guide at https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-UsingEclipseLink.

You must follow these instructions perfectly or there will be errors. However, there were two exceptions:

1. The dom4j dependency issue is not the dependency problem or is no longer a problem with the versions I used (it seems that it can be included in the dependency list in module.xml with no error - at least no errors yet).
2. Instead, there are dependency issues with an activemq artemis reference (the dependency must be added to the dependency list in module.xml). It worked using the following reference:

   ```
       module name="org.apache.activemq.artemis"
   ```

added to the dependency list or find the reference to it among the modules in your version of Wildfly (if it is included).